# How to get category ids of specific store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, store-id

I want to get category ids of specific store.

```
$product->getCategoryIds()
```

This will get all categories of product

```
Array ( [0] => 63 [1] => 178 )
```

63 is category of store 1 and 178 is category of store 2 but I want only category 63.

Comment: which code you use for get category please declare it here so i can help you

Comment: I have product collection and need only categories ids from product collection by store.

Comment: @PrincePatel did u get solution for this. i am also looking for same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` for current store and apply it in your query

Try this

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($this->storeManager->getStore());

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getId();
}
```

Comment: not working in multisite

Comment: That's intended, the OP asked for a specific store.

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari I have facing same issue in multisite  for get store category. what solution have you applied ?